# [: : integer expression expected , by systemctl status of my service that is calling a bash script in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, bash, service, ubuntu-18.04, systemd

I do not have much experience with bash scripts, but i got the idea from the internet.

My bash script uses xprintidle to shutdown after the computer is in idle for some time.

I can run the script in terminal without any problem. 
But when the /etc/systemd/system/poweroff.service is calling the script it gives the error in the systemctl status.

```
Jul 30 16:43:40 godo systemd[1]: Started autopoweroff.
Jul 30 16:43:42 godo bash[3107]: couldn't open display
Jul 30 16:43:42 godo bash[3107]: /usr/local/bin/poweroff.sh: line 5: [: : integer expression expected
Jul 30 16:43:42 godo bash[3107]: end
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2
myidle=$(xprintidle)
myidletime=$((10000))
while [ "$myidle" -le "$myidletime" ]; do
        echo $myidle
        sleep 1
        myidle=$(xprintidle)
done
#sudo shutdown -P now
#shutdown -P 5
echo "end"
```

And here is the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=autopoweroff

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/poweroff.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I hope you can help me and I do not waste your time with these beginner questions.

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `xprintidle`?

Comment: `couldn't open display` may be written to stderr by `xprintidle` and nothing to stdout, empty which is not a valid integer. the exit status of xprintidle could be checked `myidle=$(xprintidle) || exit 1` to prevent from continuing execution

Comment: The exit status of xprintidle is status=1/FAILURE .

Comment: `$((10000))`  doesn't do anything useful; `myidletime=10000` is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

When xprintidle does not have a display it print: "couldn't open display", you are trying to then compare this invalid value as an interger using "-le".

Since xprintidle returns exit code 1 when it does not have a display, you can use

```
       set -e
```

at the start of your script to exit when an error occurs.

Comment: Yes it exits at the line with xprintidle. So it does not return an integer? But is there a difference to running it in terminal, because there i got the echo output from xprintidle?

Answer (score 0):

`xprintidle` - utility printing user's idle time in X

When your script runs in the systemd context, it has no X server, so `xprintidle` fails and output `couldn't open display` to stderr.

Your statement `myidle=$(xprintidle)` causes the `myidle` assignment to fail.

At this point you have to decide what you want to do when the X environment is not available.

A possiblity, is to have `myidle` with a default 0 value:

```
typeset -i myidle # Tells Bash it is an int and default to 0 if not assigned a value
myidle=$(xprintidle 2>/dev/null) || true # no error state generated
```

I think you need another way to get the idle value of the current currently running X session.

Here it is:

```
#!/bin/dash
sleep 2
# get the X DISPLAY of the first logged-in user with a X session
DISPLAY="$(
  w --short --no-header \
    | awk '{ if( match($3, ":") ) { print $3; exit; } }'
)"
export DISPLAY

myidletime=$((10000))
while myidle=$(xprintidle 2>/dev/null) && [ "$myidle" -le $myidletime ]; do
  echo "$myidle"
  sleep 1
done
#sudo shutdown -P now
#shutdown -P 5
echo "end"
```

Comment: In terminal it shows: typeset: not found, but it works without the typeset in terminal. But as the service it still does not work: + DISPLAY=:0
+ export DISPLAY
++ xprintidle
+ myidle=
+ true
+ '[' '' -le 10000 ']'
[: : integer expression expected

Comment: @jonas99g forget that `systemd` uses `dash` and not `bash`. I changed the code in my answer to accommodate `dash`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that.

Comment: somehow it still does not run properly... but maybe i first need to understand your code to learn it.    + export DISPLAY + myidletime=50000 + xprintidle + myidle= + echo end

Comment: `xprintidle` need an X display server to talk to. In the context of `systemd` there is no DISPLAY server. What my code do with w and awk, is it extracts the X display from the first logged-in user he can find having one. Then it exports the DISPLAY variable with it.